# Some java method are null safe, some are not, how do I know?

Tags: java

Some java method is null safe, but some are not. How to distinguish them?

Comment: by null safe - you mean methods which can return `null` *without* causing problems to the caller ?

Comment: No, they presumably mean that the parameter(s) can be null without the method throwing an exception. It's a reasonable enough question, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean in terms of the parameters? The documentation should state whether or not the arguments can be null, and when they *can* be null, what semantic meaning is inferred from nullity.

Unfortunately not all documentation is clear like this - and likewise it may not specify whether the return value might be null or not... in which case all you can do is experiment or look at the source code where possible :(

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would suggest that you **assume that you cannot pass null as a parameter unless the documentation clearly states that you can and what the corresponding behaviour is**.

A problem with taking the default assumption that a parameter might be "null-safe" is that, even if that turns out to be true, it's not always clear without documentation what the corresponding behaviour actually is. "Not throwing an exception" doesn't actually indicate what alternative behaviour/default parameter/assumptions are then going to occur instead.

If you're designing an API, then where is's practical, I would suggest not actually encouraging null to be passed as a parameter to exposed methods/constructors, but rather have separate method signatures that include or not the various optional parameters. And in any case, you may then need to document in some way what actual behaviour is being taken to make up for the missing parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky, the parameter will be documented or annotated, or both. Unfortunately, most Java APIs lack both.

Some static analysis tools can use annotations to check whether you're passing a null value inappropriately. For example, the [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) tool includes support for these annotations:

- @NonNull - The value must not be null
- @CheckForNull - The value may contain null.
- @Nullable - Whether the value may contain null or not depends on context.

Comment: +1... And IntelliJ IDEA has *@NotNull/@Nullable* and real-time checking (and warnings) about probable violations.  A gigantic time-saver : )

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadocs of the methods you are trying to call.  If the javadocs don't specify this, then trial and error in a unit test is probably your best bet.